# making a div stick to the top of the screen but if scrolled back up, return to it's original position?

Tags: javascript, css

This will make a div that is position: absolute ( top: 46px ) on a page become fixed to the top of the page ( top: 0px ) when scrolled to a certain point ( the distance from the div to the top of the page )

```
$(window).scroll(function (e) {
    $el = $('#sticky');
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 46 && $el.css('position') != 'fixed') {
        $('#sticky').css({
            'position': 'fixed',
            'top': '0px'
        });
    }
});
```

BUT it doesn't reset the position of the div when you're back at the top of the page, and I want it to. Any suggestions? Also I want to make sure this is the best way to do this — if there's a css only, non-javascript solution I'm all ears.

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8uvp8/embedded/result/?

Comment: Yes exactly — but the distance of the div from the top of the page is not set by margin it's position: absolute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend either keeping the sticky content fixed or absolute, but not switching between the two.

Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/CpM8H/2/

```
$(window).scroll(function (e) {
    $scrollTopDiff = 46 - $(this).scrollTop();

    $('#sticky').css({
        'top': ( $scrollTopDiff > 0 ? $scrollTopDiff : 0 ) + 'px'
    });
});
```

Absolute: http://jsfiddle.net/CpM8H/3/

```
$(window).scroll(function (e) {
    $scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

    $('#sticky').css({
        'top': ( $scrollTop > 46 ? $scrollTop : 46 ) + 'px'
    });
});
```

If you really need to switch between fixed and absolute, here is my first though on how to do that, but the sticky content may jump around a bit:

```
$(window).scroll(function (e) {
$el = $('#sticky');
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 46 ) {
    $el.css({
        'position': 'fixed',
        'top': '0px'
    });
} else {
    $el.css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'top': '46px'
    });
}
});
```

Comment: This is very glitchy for me — did you try it?

Comment: Yeah, the sticky was flashing. Removing the conditional checking its position attribute for "fixed" seemed to fix it - you don't need that anyway. Also, you can use that $el you defined instead of getting the div again by its ID, as also shown in my edited code.
http://jsfiddle.net/CpM8H/

Comment: Wait if the div is inside a container though, it jumps out of it

Comment: That's part of the problem of changing its position attribute. Typically this kind of content would be always fixed, and its top value would be set by the scroll function to be the difference between 46 and scrollTop(), down to but not below 0. For example:
http://jsfiddle.net/CpM8H/2/

Comment: I expanded my answer to illustrate.